# How to run a Bash script that runs Python scripts using crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I have a Bash script, and in it are calls for two Python scripts. While using crontab the Bash script runs just fine but the Python scripts don't do anything, as if they aren't called or interpreted. I know it could all be done in Python, but I wanted to learn some Bash so I decided to mix them.

What might the issue be? It's hard to find answers for this as no one would mix Bash and Python since it's definitely not something useful.

My crontab is this:

```
10 * * * * cd ~/directory && /bin/bash ~/directory/script.sh >> output.txt
```

I can see Python is not doing anything by taking a look at the log.txt file that I create with Bash (code below)

The Bash script looks something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
...
var=$(python3 app.py)
...
now=$(date + ...)
echo $now $var >> log.txt
```

The code works fine in the terminal, I also have a venv and environmental variables so I don't know how impactful that could be.

(I put the output.txt in crontab just to debug, if the program was working I would only use the log.txt in the script).

Comment: Which directory contains `app.py` and which `python3`?

Comment: app.py is in the same directory as script.sh, python3 is in usr/bin/

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: This might help: replace `>> output.txt` with `>> output.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: Thank you that did definitely help. Apparently the environmental variables are not being read or there's some error with the packages, so the problem is definitely in the venv or environmental variables. Now I just gotta find it

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

The crontab has no access to the environmental variables that I had declared in .bashrc. Declaring the variables in crontab -e worked in my  OS Fedora Linux 35.

```
ENV_VAR="a"
ENV_VAR2="b"
10 * * * * cd ~/directory && /bin/bash ~/directory/script.sh >> output.txt
```

Might work if you have env variables in your Python script and run into the same problem using Fedora 35.